# Tail of List is always empty

Tags: prolog

I have a list of which i gotta extract `Size` items and that makes up the `Group`.
The remaining items in the list are the `Persons_Rest`.

My code is working perfectly fine so far, only that I have a empty tail in my `Group`, so the first variable.

I know it is, because the parameters of my accumulator method is `[Head|Tail]`. But I cant find out how to avoid the empty tail.

```
make_one_group(Group, All_Persons, Persons_rest, Size):-
    make_one_group_acc(Group, All_Persons, All_Persons, Persons_rest, 0, Size).


make_one_group_acc(Group, All_Persons, Persons_rest, Persons_rest, Size, Size).

make_one_group_acc([H_group|T_group], All_Persons, Persons_rest_acc, Persons_rest, Counter, Size) :-
    ReplaceCounter is Counter+1,
    make_one_group_acc(T_group, All_Persons, New_Persons_rest, Persons_rest, ReplaceCounter, Size),
    my_select(H_group, Persons_rest_acc, New_Persons_rest).
    

my_select(Elem, [Elem|T], T).

my_select(Elem, [H|T], [H|T2]) :-
    my_select(Elem, T, T2).
```

Comment: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: Perhaps `make_one_group_acc(Group,` should be `make_one_group_acc([],` - to close the list.